# How can I align two adjacent divs, with one wrapping the text and the other filling the rest?

Tags: html, css, web

How can I achieve the following in CSS:

The right div should have a width depending on the text (wrap_content).

The left div should fill the remaining space (width = 100% - right div).

(Assume that the right div has a max-width of 50px and for smaller text it should wrap the text)

[image: What I would like to achieve]

Comment: Do you want to cover the space above right div also with left div?

Comment: No, it should basically be an input field with a submit button on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `float` the *right* column, and hide the horizontal overflow of the *left* column by `overflow-x: hidden;`, as follows:

```css
.right {
  max-width: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.left { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="right">Text</div>
<div class="left"> ... </div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cexowabu/1/edit)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the float property for placing and following javascript to calculate the width of left input box.

```
<form>
    <div class="wrap">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Test"></a>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var inputWidth=parseInt($('.wrap').css('width'))-parseInt($('.button').css('width'))-15;
  $('input').css('width',inputWidth);
});
```

Checkout the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/xXXj8/6/